How to prevent long text from wrapping to the next line in text view
I have a LinearLayout with multiple nested views. The main view is a CardView that contains both text and a progress bar. To ensure proper spacing inside the card, I set a padding of 50dp. Without this padding, all the inner views would be centered and overlap each other, and the CardView would shrink to fit its contents. So, to prevent this, I added the padding.
However, the issue I'm facing now is that with long words, the text wraps to the next line depending on the device's width, which I don't want. I also don't want to compromise the internal spacing of the card.
You can refer to the screenshot below for a better idea:

Additionally, here's the full layout screenshot for reference:

Below is the XML layout that I'm currently using:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".FragmentResults">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
  <!-- Multiple similar layouts above and below -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/grey"
                        android:padding="50dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Masculinity"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/masculinity_score"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="50sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/masculinity_score_progress_bar"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                        android:max="100" />

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/grey"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="50dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:text="Jawline"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/jawline_score"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="50sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/jawline_score_progress_bar"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                        android:max="100" />

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

can anyone help me out with this

Have you tried setting the maximum lines as 1 using the android:maxlines attribute. However, an issue that may arise from using this attribute is that the text will be truncated. Where you may want to define a desired behaviour using the android:ellipsize attribute

@Eddie, you're right, but I want to display the full word for categorization. If I use ellipsizing, will it make sense?
For example, if I write 'Cheekbone' and it gets shortened to 'Cheekb..' due to spacing issues, will that make sense to the user? Honestly, I wouldn’t accept that either.

What about auto-sizing text? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview

Issue is android:padding="50dp"
Why you are giving this much padding? for small devices, you won't see number even...
I suggest to change padding to 5 dp and center align textview that you have for text and number (which you are already doing)...
So your card view will be as below.
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="Jawline"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jawline_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/jawline_score_progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:max="100" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

and if your text are gonna be more then add below code in first textview.
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"


im giving padding so that it can be in the card format as shown above in the image

@Player91 : can you remove and check.. still it will be in same format as image...

Actually, when I remove the padding, the progress bar aligns in the center. You might wonder why I don't just place the progress bar inside the same LinearLayout to make things easier. The issue is that doing so makes the progress bar's width too small, and I don't want to set a fixed width. That's why I added the progress bar to the parent MaterialCardView instead of the LinearLayout. and here is the image of what happen if i do it :- imgur.com/a/pxBAoNj

@Player91 : Increase android:layout_marginStart="15dp" & android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" to 50dp in this case...

I'm not sure how adjusting the start and end margins for the progress bar would make a difference here, but after setting them to 50, the layout remains the same as before. The only change is the reduced width due to the increased horizontal margin. [Image link: https://imgur.com/a/0ZXe0wI]

Remove this line from the "LinearLayout" which is the 1st child of "MaterialCardView"
android:padding="50dp"


To solve this problem, I created a custom TextView that would adjust the text size based on the available space when onLayout is called. To do this, create your own CustomTextView and then in onLayout:
    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
    if (changed || mNeedsResize) {
        val widthLimit = (right - left) - compoundPaddingLeft - compoundPaddingRight
        val heightLimit = (bottom - top) - compoundPaddingBottom - compoundPaddingTop
        resizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit)
    }
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
}

the resizeText function then should incrementally check sizes until the text is small enough to fit into the space provided by widthLimit. While doing this, keep in mind that you should have a "maximum" or "default" text size and a "minimum" size - since some devices may render the text smaller than is legible or desired. In case the spacing is too small, in my code it is ellipsized, but you could truncate, wrap, abbreviate, etc.
In the example you provide the text is a single line and it looks like it could resize a small amount to fit into the space, but still consider what happens if that is not true. Also, in my code it handles multiple lines of text, which you could simplify since you desire only a single line:
 /**
 * Resize the text size with specified width and height
 * @param width
 * @param height
 */
fun resizeText(width: Int, height: Int) {
    val text = text
    // Do not resize if the view does not have dimensions or there is no text
    if (text == null || text.length == 0 || height <= 0 || width <= 0 || mTextSize == 0f) {
        return
    }

    // Get the text view's paint object
    val textPaint = paint

    // Store the current text size
    val oldTextSize = textPaint.textSize
    // If there is a max text size set, use the lesser of that and the default text size
    var targetTextSize =
        if (mMaxTextSize > 0) min(mTextSize.toDouble(), mMaxTextSize.toDouble())
            .toFloat() else mTextSize

    // Get the required text height
    var textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize)

    // Until we either fit within our text view or we had reached our min text size, incrementally try smaller sizes
    while (textHeight > height && targetTextSize > mMinTextSize) {
        targetTextSize = max((targetTextSize - 1).toDouble(), mMinTextSize.toDouble())
            .toFloat()
        textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize)
        //Log.i(TAG, "checking text size: " + textHeight);
    }

    // If we had reached our minimum text size and still don't fit, append an ellipsis
    if (addEllipsis && targetTextSize == mMinTextSize && textHeight > height) {
        // Draw using a static layout
        val layout = StaticLayout(
            text,
            textPaint,
            width,
            Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
            mSpacingMult,
            mSpacingAdd,
            false
        )
        // Check that we have a least one line of rendered text
        if (layout.lineCount > 0) {
            // Since the line at the specific vertical position would be cut off,
            // we must trim up to the previous line
            val lastLine = layout.getLineForVertical(height) - 1
            // If the text would not even fit on a single line, clear it
            if (lastLine < 0) {
                setText("")
            } else {
                val start = layout.getLineStart(lastLine)
                var end = layout.getLineEnd(lastLine)
                var lineWidth = layout.getLineWidth(lastLine)
                val ellipseWidth = textPaint.measureText(mEllipsis)

                // Trim characters off until we have enough room to draw the ellipsis
                while (width < lineWidth + ellipseWidth) {
                    lineWidth =
                        textPaint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, --end + 1).toString())
                }
                setText(text.subSequence(0, end).toString() + mEllipsis)
            }
        }
    }

    // Some devices try to auto adjust line spacing, so force default line spacing
    // and invalidate the layout as a side effect
    textPaint.textSize = targetTextSize
    setLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult)

    // Notify the listener if registered
    if (mTextResizeListener != null) {
        mTextResizeListener!!.onTextResize(this, oldTextSize, targetTextSize)
    }

    // Reset force resize flag
    mNeedsResize = false
}

The mNeedsResize flag is to handle dynamic cases, for example if you change other elements of the screen that impacts the size of the CardView - you can probably ignore this in your case. Similarly, instead of an ellipsis, you could customize how the text is abbreviated using a Map or something similar, since you have pre-selected text. For my case, this was dynamic text.
Similarly, you can probably ignore the multi-line checks since you desire a single line. But in the future you may have titles that have 2 lines? Again, I needed it but you may not.
Good luck!

thanks for the help, but the issue still persists. Right now, if I reduce the padding to 40-45 dp, the text view displays correctly as I intended, but this only works on one device. I can't guarantee it will look the same on most users' devices.

android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"

Referencing : android singleLine vs maxLines
